# Distinct all columns in a datatable and store to another datatable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable with more than 10 columns and I would like to distinct all columns and then store a result to another datatable.

Is there any way to distinct all columns in a datatable by using LINQ without naming all ones?

I've tried as the code below but it just give one row. Please give me any advice for this case.

```
DataTable dtPurchaseOrder = new DataTable();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PONumber");
dt.Columns.Add("Customer");
dt.Columns.Add("Address");
dt.Rows.Add("PO123456", "MH", "123");
dt.Rows.Add("PO123456", "MH", "123");
dt.Rows.Add("PO654321", "AB", "123");
dt.Rows.Add("PO654321", "AB", "123");

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    var lstPO = (from row in dtPurchaseOrder.AsEnumerable()
                 select row.Field<string>("PONumber")).Count();
    if (lstPO == 0)
        dtPurchaseOrder.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
}

dtPurchaseOrder.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Define `PrimaryKey` to your `Datatable` .

Comment: @HariPrasad Thank you for you reply. Please give me more information about what the PrimaryKey is in the Datatable?

Comment: You could potentially use `String.Join` and the `ItemArray` of the row to create a single `String` that represents the entire row and then get distinct values of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Simplest solution would be [`DefaultView.ToTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "PONumber", "Customer", "Address");
```

**Solution 2 :**

Another alternative would be using `Linq` statement to filter distinct rows and then looping them as required.

```
var result =  dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => new {
                PONumber = row.Field<string>("PONumber"),
                Customer = row.Field<string>("Customer"),
                Address = row.Field<string>("Address")
            }).Distinct();
```

**Solution 3 :**

Traditional way of checking existence with `PrimaryKey` defined.

```
var ponum = dtPurchaseOrder.Columns.Add("PONumber");
var cust = dtPurchaseOrder.Columns.Add("Customer");
var address = dtPurchaseOrder.Columns.Add("Address");


dtPurchaseOrder.PrimaryKey =  new[] {ponum, cust, address};

dt.Rows.Add("PO123456", "MH", "123");
dt.Rows.Add("PO654321", "AB", "123");
dt.Rows.Add("PO654321", "AB", "123");



foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    var exisiting = dtPurchaseOrder.Rows.Find(r.ItemArray);

    if (exisiting == null)  
    {
        dtPurchaseOrder.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
    }       
}
```

Working [Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/liu86I)

Comment: Thank you for your all solutions. That works pretty well. However, I got an error with the DataColum cannot be `null`. How to allow the column can be null as `AllowDBNull`?

Answer (score 2):

A way to distinct the table without defining the column name

```
var dtPurchaseOrder = dt
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default)
                      .CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I've tried but the datatable does not bind to my DataGridView.

Comment: All I had to do is to cast `dtPurchaseOrder` back into dt.This gave me exactly what I needed.ie. `dt = (Datatable)dtPurchaseOrder;`